# Double vote after migration?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, migration

While my memory is sometimes write-only, I think I've already voted on that question: [Receiving notifications for new questions with specific tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250068/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results)

Now I could vote once again.

Is it by design? I haven't expected double-vote extra power ;)

Comment: [Migrated question's answers can be upvoted twice by the same user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user) - Although the reason given by Jeff there doesn't really explain why it's not a bug. "It's a different site" doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The unicorns granted this wish to us :)

Comment: @animuson yeah, after reading that I'm quite sure what's happening. I think it's a duck meme: if you can't fix it, it's not a bug...

Answer (score 9):

This is a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user). The [official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user/20210#20210) is

> How is this a bug? You're voting on a completely different website. There is no cross-site voting "protection".

Which makes sense — the votes on the origin site and on the destination site reflect different perspectives. The proper solution to double voting isn't in fact to prevent voting on the destination site if you've already voted on the origin site, but to not transfer the vote from the origin site. In other words, [reset votes on migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions).

Which was [rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions/151893#151893) for a completely different reason that makes absolutely no sense to me.